# Change Javascript cookies redirection

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

i found this javascript that allow you to chose an option and once you click the go button. It will redirect you to another site. I have try modify this so i can use it with a button instead of a radio but it doesn't seem to work. Can any 1 help me out ??

Thank you very much.

here the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    //chose which page to go to
    function Link() {
      if (document.fred.r1[0].checked) {
        window.top.location = 'http://kshowonline.com/list';
      }
      if (document.fred.r1[1].checked) {
        window.top.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
      }
      if (document.fred.r1[2].checked) {
        window.top.location = 'https://www.yahoo.com/';
      }
      if (document.fred.r1[3].checked) {
        window.top.location = 'https://nodejs.org/';
      }
    }

     //-->
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="f19_GetFormCookie();Link();">
  <form title="f19_Include" name="fred">
    <INPUT type="radio" name="r1">Baseball
    <INPUT type="radio" name="r1">Basketball
    <INPUT type="radio" name="r1">Soccer
    <INPUT type="radio" name="r1">Fencing
    <INPUT type="button" value="GO" onclick="f19_SetFormCookie();Link();">
  </form>

  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--


     // A Cookie Script to Store and Retrieve
     // the values and states of common form elements
     // TEXT BOXES - value
     // TEXT AREA - value
     // CHECK BOX - checked state
     // RADIO BUTTON - checked state
     // SELECT LIST - selected Index

     // Application Notes and Customising Variables

     // Application Notes

     // Values and states of each element are stored
     // as the page is unloaded or form submitted.

     // The storage duration is specified by a customising variable

     // Stored values and states of elements included in the cookie
     // are re-established as the page is reloaded.

     // The number and type of elements included must respect
     // the maximum cookie size of 4K.

     // The Retrieval is initialised by a <BODY> onload event
     // The Storage occurs on a <BODY> onunload event
     // e.g.
     // <body onload="f19_GetFormCookie();" onunload="f19_SetFormCookie();" >


     // To include a form element in the Store and Retrieve
     // it must be child nodes of an element with a title of 'f19_Include'
     // e.g.
     // <span title="f19_Include" >
     // <INPUT type="text" size="10" >
     // <INPUT type="checkbox >
     // </span>

     // There may be any number of elements titled 'f19_Include' on a page
     // and as many child elements of each 'f19_Include' as required.

     // All variable, function etc. names are prefixed with 'f19_'
     // to minimise conflicts with other JavaScripts


     // Customising Variables

    var f19_Days = 1; // The cookie will be available on revisits for a specified number of days
    var f19_Cookie = 'My Form2'; // The Cookie name

     //-->
  </script>

  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
     // Form Compendium f19_Part2 (12-05-2005)



     // Functional Code

     // No Need To Change ***************************
    var f19_TBAry = new Array();
    var f19_RCAry = new Array();
    var f19_TAAry = new Array();
    var f19_SLAry = new Array();

    var f19_TBString, f19_RCString, f19_TAString, f19_SLString;
    var f19_, f19_exp, f19_st, f19_len, f19_end, f19_st;

    var f19_Exp = new Date(new Date().getTime() + f19_Days * 86400000).toGMTString();

    function f19_GetFormCookie() {
      f19_TBString = f19_GetCookie(f19_Cookie + 'TB');
      f19_RCString = f19_GetCookie(f19_Cookie + 'RC');
      f19_SLString = f19_GetCookie(f19_Cookie + 'SL');
      f19_TAString = f19_GetCookie(f19_Cookie + 'TA');
      f19_ = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
      for (f19_0 = 0; f19_0 < f19_.length; f19_0++) {
        if (f19_[f19_0].title == 'f19_Include') {
          f19_Inc = f19_[f19_0].getElementsByTagName('*');
          for (f19_1 = 0; f19_1 < f19_Inc.length; f19_1++) {
            if (f19_Inc[f19_1].tagName == 'INPUT') {
              if (f19_Inc[f19_1].type == 'text') {
                f19_TBAry[f19_TBAry.length] = f19_Inc[f19_1];
              }
              if (f19_Inc[f19_1].type == 'radio' || f19_Inc[f19_1].type == 'checkbox') {
                f19_RCAry[f19_RCAry.length] = f19_Inc[f19_1];
              }
            }
            if (f19_Inc[f19_1].tagName == 'TEXTAREA') {
              f19_TAAry[f19_TAAry.length] = f19_Inc[f19_1];
            }
            if (f19_Inc[f19_1].tagName == 'SELECT') {
              f19_SLAry[f19_SLAry.length] = f19_Inc[f19_1];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (f19_TBString) {
        for (f19_1 = 0; f19_1 < f19_TBAry.length; f19_1++) {
          f19_TBAry[f19_1].value = f19_TBString.split('~^~')[f19_1];
        }
      }
      if (f19_RCString) {
        for (f19_2 = 0; f19_2 < f19_RCAry.length; f19_2++) {
          f19_RCAry[f19_2].checked = false;
          if (f19_RCString.split('~^~')[f19_2] == 'true') {
            f19_RCAry[f19_2].checked = true;
          }
        }
      }
      if (f19_TAString) {
        for (f19_3 = 0; f19_3 < f19_TAAry.length; f19_3++) {
          f19_TAAry[f19_3].value = f19_TAString.split('~^~')[f19_3];
        }
      }
      if (f19_SLString) {
        for (f19_4 = 0; f19_4 < f19_SLAry.length; f19_4++) {
          f19_SLAry[f19_4].selectedIndex = f19_SLString.split('~^~')[f19_4];
        }
      }
    }

    function f19_GetCookie(name) {
      var f19_st = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
      var f19_len = f19_st + name.length + 1;
      if ((!f19_st) && (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) return null;
      if (f19_st == -1) return null;
      var f19_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", f19_len);
      if (f19_end == -1) f19_end = document.cookie.length;
      return decodeURI(document.cookie.substring(f19_len, f19_end));
    }

    function f19_SetFormCookie(value) {
      f19_TBString = '';
      for (f19_0 = 0; f19_0 < f19_TBAry.length; f19_0++) {
        f19_TBString += f19_TBAry[f19_0].value + '~^~';
      }
      document.cookie = f19_Cookie + "TB=" + encodeURI(f19_TBString) + ";expires=" + f19_Exp + ";path=/;"
      f19_RCString = '';
      for (f19_1 = 0; f19_1 < f19_RCAry.length; f19_1++) {
        f19_RCString += f19_RCAry[f19_1].checked + '~^~';
      }
      document.cookie = f19_Cookie + "RC=" + encodeURI(f19_RCString) + ";expires=" + f19_Exp + ";path=/;"
      f19_TAString = '';
      for (f19_0 = 0; f19_0 < f19_TAAry.length; f19_0++) {
        f19_TAString += f19_TAAry[f19_0].value + '~^~';
      }
      document.cookie = f19_Cookie + "TA=" + encodeURI(f19_TAString) + ";expires=" + f19_Exp + ";path=/;"
      f19_SLString = '';
      for (f19_1 = 0; f19_1 < f19_SLAry.length; f19_1++) {
        f19_SLString += f19_SLAry[f19_1].selectedIndex + '~^~';
      }
      document.cookie = f19_Cookie + "SL=" + encodeURI(f19_SLString) + ";expires=" + f19_Exp + ";path=/;"
    }


     //-->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why javascript ? Why not links ?

Comment: The javascript is for creating/storing cookies so it need to be there. What I need is  to modify the type="radio" to type="button" and still have this working normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick event on radio buttons: 
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/onclick-onchange.php

You could modify your code to use Buttons instead RadioButtons.
It should resemble the following:

```
   <button  name="b1" onclick="f19_SetFormCookie('Baseball')">Baseball</button>
   <button  name="b2" onclick="f19_SetFormCookie('Basketball')">Basketball</button>
   <button  name="b3" onclick="f19_SetFormCookie('Soccer')">Soccer</button>
   <button  name="b4" onclick="f19_SetFormCookie('Fencing')">Fencing</button>
```

Then you'll have to modify SetFormCookie function to accept the argument - based on which cookie will be set.

Comment: is there a way to change the type to "button" instead of "radio" and still make this work ?  Because i prefer the option box to have no check mark and able to have hover effect.

Comment: i think there some modification needed in Link() for button type to work, but i'm not sure what to change .